# Trying to resolve Pkgdef error

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I am running scripts in Sql server management studio and something is causing  SSMS to reset. After some investigation and reading the message that pops up, I run the application from the command line and use the /log switch. reviewing the log I find this error :

> PkgDef encountered data collision in section
>   'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\SQL Server Management
>   Studio\11.0_Config\CLSID{00a2c8fe-3844-41be-9637-167454a7f1a7}' for
>   value 'Assembly'

this is just one example...there are many. So I look online for pkgdef troubleshooting tips and found one site...http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/03/22/troubleshooting-pkgdef-files.aspx

this told me the following:

> Issue: Registry Value Collisions Sometimes the same registry value is
>   being set by more than one pkgdef file. In other cases, a registry
>   value is being set, but it’s not clear which pkgdef file is doing it.
>   You can either scan all of the pkgdef files and discover where the
>   value is being set. Or use /log again. Remedy: Use /log to discover
>   which pkgdef(s) set a value To discover all pkgdef files that are
>   setting a value, use a simple trick: explicitly set that same value by
>   temporarily changing the master pkgdef (C:\Program Files\Microsoft
>   Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.pkgdef) to explicitly set the
>   value before all of the other pkgdef files are processed. This will
>   require Administrator rights to edit the file, but is otherwise
>   straightforward. Make a backup copy of devenv.pkgdef, then bring it up
>   in an editor. Below the [$Initialization$] section, add a new section
>   for the parent key of the value. Then add the key value below it, save
>   it, and run devenv.exe with /log. The pkgdef loader will log all of
>   the additional writes to that value, along with the path to the
>   offending pkgdef.

I found the devenv.pkgdef file but i really don't understand how to modify the file as it suggests.
I would like to know how to modify the file(with example) to find the problem and then to fix it. 
Thanks for your patience

Comment: Did you ever get around resolving these warnings?

Comment: it turns out that it was a different issue and that there was no solution that we could implement